# CodeIgniter - How to logout other user

Tags: php, codeigniter, logout, codeigniter-3

In my application Admin can view the client list if he wish he can logout the user from the application.   Can any one help me how to do such type of functionality?

Comment: logout means disable user login? is it ??

Comment: No, user can can login any time force logout due to if that user close browser without logout or for some matter admin need to force logout the user. Thank you

Comment: Its depends on the browser thy logged in. I think this will cant reach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to setup a token logging session. When a user logs in they receive a SESSION token. That token is stored in a database and on each page load you check whether that token is still valid. If not then redirect the user to the login page. This will also show an admin user valid tokens (i.e. potentially active/logged in users) and also gives the option to remove/log them out by deactivating their token.

Unfortunately this is massive code so I can't "do it for you" but a database with tokens will be your starting point and I've created full functionality using this method.